# Target class with JQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following code,

```
<span class="rpText">
  <img class="favMenuItemImg" alt="arrow" src="Images/rightArrow.png">
  <b>
     <i>New Products</i>
  </b>
</span>

<span class="rpText">
  <img class="favMenuItemBlankImg" alt="" src="Images/transparent.png">
    Profile
  </span>
</span>
```

and I want to target the favMenuItemBlankImg class and only set the favorite image if there is this class.

I tried the following JQuery:-

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.get_count() ; i++) {
    if (!$(this).siblings('span.rpText.favMenuItemBlankImg '))
    {
        items.getItem(i).set_imageUrl("Images/favorites_small.png");
    }
}
```

but this is not working.

JQUERY UPDATE---------------------------------------------------------

```
if (item.get_text() == "Favorites") {
    panelItem = panel.findItemByText(item.get_text());
    var items = panelItem.get_items();

    for (var i = 0; i < items.get_count() ; i++) {

        $('img.favMenuItemBlankImg').each(function () {
            $(this)[i].getItem(i).set_imageUrl("Images/favorites_small.png");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: proper tags for bold or italics are `<strong>` and `<em>`

Comment: It probably would be even more proper to use CSS `font-weight` and `font-style`

Comment: I don't see the link between your jQuery code and the check on whether the element is bold and italic...

Comment: Please rephrase your question as it really seems like a jumble of several as it sits currently - your title does not match your question and that does not match the code sample even remotely.

Comment: You are right Samuel , I did change the class of the transparent to favMenuItemBlankImg but I still cannot target the favMenuItemImg.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I did, you were right it was confusing

Answer (score 1):

Find items with a class and set the src?

```
$('img.favMenuItemBlankImg').attr('src',"Images/favorites_small.png");
```

EDIT per comment: something like these for the indexed value perhaps?

```
$('img.favMenuItemBlankImg').each(function(i){
   $(this)[i].set_imageUrl("Images/favorites_small.png");
});
```

OR

```
$('img.favMenuItemBlankImg').each(function(i){
   $(this)[i].getItem(i).set_imageUrl("Images/favorites_small.png");
});
```

Comment: the only problem is that I am replacing the actual transparent image at the moment and don't want that.  Its important to me to use this line    items.getItem(i).set_imageUrl("Images/favorites_small.png"); since I am using a third party control

Comment: So I need to do something like if(the image class is favMenuItemBlankImg.............

Comment: I tried if ($('img').hasClass("favMenuItemBlankImg")) but still not working

Comment: hi Mark, I updated the Jquery bit of my question with your solution, however I still cannot manage to view the favorite image

Comment: still struggling with this

Comment: I don't think you need the for loop - and put the 'i' in the function as I have it here - that should loop through them with 'i' set to the index of each one - ALL this without any knowledge of your third party thing which may be your issue.

Comment: If there is no for loop, from where will I get the (index)?

Comment: removed the for and included the (i) again inside the function, still not working though

Comment: Sorry Mark had to remove it since its not the answer I am after.  I still did not manage to get it right

Comment: Not surprised but this is the best we can do here with the limited information available.

Comment: Hey Mark, you are right, and I changed my code quite a bit now.  I added a MouseOver and MouseOut which are working better for what I want to achieve, however still have a nagging problem with targeting a particular <li>.  I am using a third party control as I said before, and its quite hard to target particular items without <divs>.  Shall I Update my question with the latest code and the HTML output I am targetting?

Comment: Probably a new question it would seem - post markup and code to a new question with exactly what you desire/have an issue with NOW :)

Answer (score 0):

A much better approach would be using a `title` class that gives the text bold and italic, then search for that class.

The CSS

```
.title {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

The HTML

```
<span class="rpText">
    <img class="favMenuItemImg" alt="arrow" src="Images/rightArrow.png">
    <span class="title">New Products</span>
</span>

<span class="rpText">
    <img class="favMenuItemImg" alt="" src="Images/transparent.png">
    <span>
        Profile 
    </span>
</span>
```

The jQuery

```
$("img.favMenuItemImg").next().each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("title")) {
        //do what you want
    }
});
```

Here's a fiddle demoing the concept: http://jsfiddle.net/xAPfu/

Answer (score 0):

It would definitely be better to use font-weight and font-style in your code as @tymeJV suggests, but if your stuck with `<b>` and `<i>`, you can select find "titles" like this:

```
$.each($('.rpText'),function(i,e){
    if ($(e).find('b').length>0) {
       alert ($(this).html()); //this element has 'b'
    }
});
```